# Having Attributes of an Item in SimpleDB to be sorted

Tags: java, sorting, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to display a SimpleDB query and noticed that the order of the attributes are not always the same per query.

For example, one query result might look like:

```
Item
  URL:....
  Date:...
```

then another query might look like this:

```
Item
  Date:...
  URL:....
```

The `order by` sorts out each item but does it sort the attributes? is there a way to always have the attributes sorted in an alphabetical order?

I am using java to access the db.

Query: `selectExpression = "select * from`" + "urls`where url = '" + "stack.com" +"'";`

Comment: Can you please post the query

Comment: i have updated my question with the queury

Comment: You could use "Select URL,Date from urls where url="something"

Comment: tried but doesn't seem to be ordering though

Answer (score 0):

```
selectExpression = "select * from" + "urlswhere url = '" + "stack.com" +"' order by          {column} DESC";
```

Replace the {column} with required column name

Comment: Not quite understand. if I put `selectExpression = "select * from" + "urlswhere url = '" + "stack.com" +"' order by URL desc";` I get an error `InvalidSortExpression`

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS, `Amazon SimpleDB supports sorting data on a single attribute`. I will have to write my own comparator to do the sorting since it there is no guarantee of order for multiple attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Simple DB does not support listing the attributes in the same order because Amazon Simple DB provides flexibility to add new attributes that only applies to certain rows therefore each row may have different-different attributes and Amazon SimpleDB does not guarantee the order of records returned.